# Is there a file chooser available for box.com?

Tags: box-api

Similar to the file [chooser for dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser) is there one for box.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box does not maintain its own "file chooser" currently; however, there is an awesome service called filepicker.io which acts as a "file chooser" for almost every cloud service, including Box. You can find their documentation here: https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/

Comment: filepicker.io is quite expensive for what it does. On the cheaper plans you're limited to 100mb file size and not until you're paying close to 500 a month can you transfer files larger than 1GB. (This is a major issue for clients dealing with large audio or video files.)

Additionally it basically saves the file to their servers rather than just providing a 'pass-through' mechanism like DropBox's chooser API does.

Answer (score 7):

Box now has it's own file picker.  See https://box-content.readme.io/docs/the-box-file-picker

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a single file chooser for Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, SharePoint, OneDrive, and more with the [Kloudless File Picker](https://github.com/kloudless/file-picker/). (I work at Kloudless)